# How do I figure out which package is causing my black screen issues?

Tags: package-management, kernel, radeon, bug-reporting, debugging

I am getting a black screen on different linux distributions (Ubuntu 18.04, Kubuntu 18.04, Manjaro GNOME 17.1.12) as long as only one monitor is enabled and connected. When 2 monitors are connected and enabled, I never got a black screen.

The black screen issue does not occur with Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. I suspected it is a bug in the kernel.
But if I install the old kernel on Ubuntu 18.04, the issue still exists. So it can't be the kernel, right? How do I figure out which package is causing the issues? (So I can report a bug at the right place.)

**Additional Infos:**

- Even though it may not be the kernel, I did create a [bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1793934)
- Hardware: AMD Radeon R9 390, Intel i5-4570, ASRock H87 Pro4

Comment: It's likely the kernel graphics driver. Why would you expect the older kernel work but not the newer? It usually the opposite: the newest kernel *(development versions aside)* works, but not the older. It's good that you reported to launchpad, and I see someone already started looking into it. But in case it will get silent over there, you can report to the [kernel bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/) *(you'll need to make sure you tried mainline kernel, but I see in your report, you already did)*. The component is AMDGPU driver.

Comment: I expected the old kernel would work, because I tried the old version that is used in Ubuntu 16.04, where the issue did not exist.
Thank you for your help, Hi-Angel!